# error: invalid path 'images /Screen Shot 2020-10-06 at 8.04.00 PM.jpg' file was created on a mac

Tags: github

I am not sure why I am getting a file path error when I try to pull this repository.  Original photos were png files, but get the same error when changed to jpg.  Files are uploaded from a Mac, and I am using Windows.

```
error: invalid path 'images /Capture.jpg'
error: invalid path 'images /Screen Shot 2020-10-06 at 8.04.00 PM.jpg'
error: invalid path 'images /Screen Shot 2020-10-06 at 8.08.10 PM.jpg'
error: invalid path 'images /image (2).jpg'
```